# I just updated the NetBeans 8 to 8.0.2. I get 'The provided LESS compiler is not valid' when I opened my old project

Tags: css, netbeans, less

I just updated the NetBeans 8 to 8.0.2. I get 'The provided LESS compiler is not valid', when I opened my old project.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, it happened because when i opened a less file it asked me to enable Less compiler, so i did, but the functionality is not installed in my computer so it can't find the compiler.

To solve it, go to Project Properties and select "CSS Preprocessors", click on the LESS tab and unselect "Compile LESS files on save"